# values coming as 0 or null through rest API react native/spring boot

Tags: javascript, java, rest, spring-boot, react-native

I'm trying to send some data from my frontend (react native) to my middleware (spring boot), and for some reason the values are coming as 0 and null. sending the exact same object through postman works just fine. I've tried surrounding the names of the parameters with " like `"quizId":2`, it also doesn't work. I've use this exact method below before with great success. I'm clueless as to how this is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated.

endpoint:

```
void recordScore(@RequestBody Score score){
    System.out.println(score);
    serv.recordScore(score);
}
```

console output from sysout above when sending from react native:

```
Score(quizId=0, staffId=0, totalScore=0.0, userQuizRecords=null, timeTaken=0, correctAns=0, takenDate=null)
```

console output when using postman:

```
Score(quizId=3, staffId=405986, totalScore=30.0, userQuizRecords=[UserQuizRecord(id=0, staffId=405986, quizId=2, questionId=5, score=4, correctAns=true, takenDate=null), UserQuizRecord(id=0, staffId=405986, quizId=2, questionId=6, score=1, correctAns=false, takenDate=null), UserQuizRecord(id=0, staffId=405986, quizId=2, questionId=7, score=4, correctAns=true, takenDate=null), UserQuizRecord(id=0, staffId=405986, quizId=2, questionId=8, score=3, correctAns=false, takenDate=null)], timeTaken=400, correctAns=4, takenDate=null)
```

js:

```
let score = {
      quizId: 2,
      staffId: 405986,
      totalScore: 30,
      userQuizRecords: [{
              staffId: 405986,
              quizId: 2,
              questionId: 5,
              score: 4,
              correctAns: true
          },
          {
              staffId: 405986,
              quizId: 2,
              questionId: 6,
              score: 1,
              correctAns: false
          },
          {
              staffId: 405986,
              quizId: 2,
              questionId: 7,
              score: 4,
              correctAns: true
          },
          {
              staffId: 405986,
              quizId: 2,
             questionId: 8,
              score: 3,
              correctAns:false
          }
      ],
      timeTaken: 400,
      correctAns: 4
    }
```

fetch:

```
return fetch(apis.recordScore, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                score:score
            })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try stringify the object without the curly brackets

```
body: JSON.stringify(score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're sending the exact same data using postman?

It's probably going wrong here:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
    score:score
})
```

try it without the wrapping score object

```
body: JSON.stringify(score)
```

I can't see your Score definition from here but I assume it's not defined as having a
member property called score with all fields encapsulated in that sub field.